# rails multiple .each issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using mongoid with my rails and am having a slight issue with running multiple `.each`

I have 3 models:  `Users`, `Places', and 'Posts'

`Users` and `Places` both has_many `Posts`  and `Posts` belongs_to both `Users` and `Places`

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  has_many :posts
}
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_many :posts
}
class Post
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
include Mongoid::Paperclip

belongs_to :place
belongs_to :user
}
```

i have a method on my user model to get all the users within my friends, including myself like so:

```
def self.as_objects_with_self(id)
    friends = Array.new
    self.as_ids_with_self(id).each do | friend |
      friends << User.find(friend)
    end
    friends

  end
```

This returns back an array of all my friends including myself.

What I am trying to do, is get a list of my friends and myself, and under each user have a list of their posts, and within each post have a reference to the place it is tied to...  most of this is working

```
resources = Friendship.as_objects_with_self(current_user.id)
resources.each do |resource|
  if resource.posts.count > 0
    resource[:posts] = resource.posts.all

    resource[:posts].each do |post|
      post[:place] = Place.find(post[:place])
    end
  end
end
```

The only part to this that isn't working, is the `.each` on my `:posts`.  I can see in the logs that it's searching the place table, but nothing is being added to the collection.

It adds this output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "556e26844a75730453170000",
        "authentication_token": "Q6R4FNs5i3n1-zfQfbp8",
        "created_at": "2015-06-02T21:56:20.684Z",
        "dob": "1982-08-01",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "last_action": null,
        "name": "tester1",
        "picture_content_type": null,
        "picture_file_name": null,
        "picture_file_size": null,
        "picture_fingerprint": null,
        "picture_updated_at": null,
        "picture_url": "/pictures/original/missing.png",
        "posts": [
            {
                "_id": "556e32b54a75730453270000",
                "created_at": "2015-06-02T22:48:21.962Z",
                "media_content_type": null,
                "media_file_name": null,
                "media_file_size": null,
                "media_fingerprint": null,
                "media_updated_at": null,
                "picture_content_type": "image/jpeg",
                "picture_file_name": "8580243774_479d5fe7bf_z.jpg",
                "picture_file_size": 191938,
                "picture_fingerprint": "61bdc1d21158c76d601b028bf826b437",
                "picture_updated_at": "2015-06-02T22:48:21.768+00:00",
                "place_id": "556cd5dc4a75730453010000",
                "type": "picture",
                "updated_at": "2015-06-02T22:48:21.962Z",
                "user_id": "556e26844a75730453170000"
            },
            {
                "_id": "556e351f4a75730453280000",
                "created_at": "2015-06-02T22:58:39.761Z",
                "media_content_type": null,
                "media_file_name": null,
                "media_file_size": null,
                "media_fingerprint": null,
                "media_updated_at": null,
                "picture_content_type": "image/jpeg",
                "picture_file_name": "8580243774_479d5fe7bf_z.jpg",
                "picture_file_size": 191938,
                "picture_fingerprint": "61bdc1d21158c76d601b028bf826b437",
                "picture_updated_at": "2015-06-02T22:58:39.571+00:00",
                "place_id": "556cd5dc4a75730453010000",
                "type": "picture",
                "updated_at": "2015-06-02T22:58:39.761Z",
                "user_id": "556e26844a75730453170000"
            }
        ],
        "telephone": "5555555555",
        "thumb_picture_url": "/pictures/thumbnail/missing.png",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-02T21:56:20.705Z",
        "username": "tester1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "556cd5934a75730453000000",
        "authentication_token": "RErefcuH5eDsSaNw6gCB",
        "created_at": "2015-06-01T21:58:43.198Z",
        "dob": "1982-08-01",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "last_action": null,
        "name": "tester",
        "picture_content_type": null,
        "picture_file_name": null,
        "picture_file_size": null,
        "picture_fingerprint": null,
        "picture_updated_at": null,
        "picture_url": "/pictures/original/missing.png",
        "telephone": "5555555555",
        "thumb_picture_url": "/pictures/thumbnail/missing.png",
        "updated_at": "2015-06-01T21:58:43.200Z",
        "username": "tester"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with `each`. It's either with `Place.find` or with `resource[:posts]`

Try to replace

```
post[:place] = Place.find(post[:place])
```

with

```
post[:place] = Place.find(post[:place_id])
```

--- edit ----

replace

```
resource[:posts].each do |post|
  post[:place] = Place.find(post[:place])
end
```

with

```
resource[:posts].map! do |post|
  post[:place_id] = Place.find(post[:place_id])
  post
end
```

or

```
resource[:posts].each.with_index do |post, i|
  resource[:posts][i][:place] = Place.find(post[:place_id])
end
```

or

```
resource.posts.each do |post|
  post[:place] = Place.find(post.place)
end
```

Comment: Same thing.  I even tried to do `post[:test] = "test"` and it didn't show either.  but doing `resource[:test] = "test"` from within the 2nd `each` did work.

Though I know it's working via:

`MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=yago_dev collection=places selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('556cd5dc4a75730453010000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.3870ms`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  Though I tried doing just .last instead of .all and then doing it for a single one, and it works fine.  So it's something to do with the array of them that's causing it to fail.

Comment: I ended up fixing it.  Not sure what the difference is but I did:

    `resource.posts.each do |post|`
        `post[:place] = Place.find(post.place)`
    `end`

and it seems to work great.

Comment: Not sure why but in the future if you need to debug issues like these install `pry` gem and drop `binding.pry` inside the loop. You'll be able to investigate all the objects you're dealing with. Anyway I'm glad you solved it.